# Windows Task Bar Item flashes when I click on it rather than opening

Tags: windows-7

I'm using aero but the same issue occurs whether or not I use it.
When I click on some programs on my taskbar rather than make the windows themselves appear they just flash in the taskbar as if they have been activated.

It has been occuring for a while but occasionally it goes away for while, really not sure why.

If anyone could help me I'd be rather grateme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Try right-clicking the program on the taskbar to see what options are provided in its menu; it might be that an option besides "Open" is default, such as acknowledging a new message, etc.
- It might be that the window for the program *is* open, but not visible, due to multiple monitors or a glitch in the program's settings. One way to fix this is to shift + right-click on the taskbar button, select "Move" and then tap an arrow key on your keyboard to lock the mouse cursor to the window. Finally, move your mouse cursor and the program window should snap into visible monitor real estate.
- Some programs have options to show in the Notification Area (by the clock, once called the system tray), or as taskbar programs or both (for example, WinAmp). You might want to look at your program settings to see if it offers this option. In some cases, double-clicking the notification area icon brings the window back, but single- or double-clicking the taskbar button seems to do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It happened to me also after one of the notification pop-up got frozen. Try to start Task Manager, go to processes and kill explorer.exe, and go back to the first tab "Applications" and press "New Task..." button and type "explorer.exe" and press "OK" button. Hopefully new instance of the explorer will rectify Areo bug.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I had to kill **Windows Expolorer** and then run it again.

1. Open **Task Manager** (CTRL-ALT-DEL and then select Task Manager)
2. Switch to the **Processes** tab
3. Right-click **explorer.exe** and select **End Process**
4. Then in the **File** menu of the Task Manager select **New Task (Run...)** and type **explorer.exe**

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a pop-up menu that appears when you click the icon in tray.
Usually this pop-up menu closes when it loses focus, but for me that pop-up menu contained only one item, and that item was disabled. When I clicked on the application window, this pop-up menu, surprisingly, didn't disappear.
Killing and starting new `explorer.exe` didn't help (yes, I killed **all** of them). Then I noticed this weird pop-up menu, clicked inside inside it, then clicked outside. Pop-up menu disappeared. I started explorer.exe and taskbar buttons started working again (i.e. when I click on them, I switched to the corresponding application window).